# Apache Rewrite specific domains to subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all domains from a specific directory to a new subdomain (invisibly).

e.g. `example.com/literal/some/path/to/file.html` -> `sub.example.com/literal/some/path/to/file.html`
AND

`www.example.com/literal/some/path/to/file.html` -> 
`www.sub.example.com/literal/some/path/to/file.html`

Where "literal" should be constant, and anything that comes after it is arbitrary.

I've tried things like

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/literal
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L]`

But I can't get all the options right. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *HTTP redirect* is a visible method that causes the browser to go somewhere else, so it by definition rules your *invisibly* out. Depending on which one you prefer and is the new subdomain on the same server you have three alternative options.

- As simple redirects as this one can be done with [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) `Redirect`. This will change the location on address bar.
- If the content is on the same server and you want to invisibly rewrite the URL, the [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)'s `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` are suitable. Just use local path instead of `http://` in your `RewriteRule`'s *substitution*.
- If you need content from `sub.example.com` on an external server but don't want the location to change, you need to set up a *reverse proxy*  with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Once you have decided, your use case is a text book case: you can find a suitable example from any of the linked documentations.